# how to using tor in linux?

Tags: vpn, tor

I live in Iran, and I wanted to filter the country most of the time. How to use the tour, which is not the terminal and the browser. I can not open my Facebook because the filter
And I'm writing to the terminal on the tor, or this way
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tor "service" set up and running successfully. Now you need to make your browser to connect to internet through tor. Because when you start tor, your network connections will not automatically be directed into tor (unlike what you see in VPN programs).

Tor is a SOCKS proxy, and you must give it's IP and port to your web browser to take advantage of it (like old HTTP proxies that we used in Iran years ago before enhancing internet filtering infrastructures, if you remember that era!)

There is two ways to use Tor with Chromium Browser (or Firefox):

- The stupid (but simple) method is to launch your browser using `torify` command. just precede your browser with torify like `torify chromium-browser`. You can use this method for any application or command line utility!
- The recommended method is to use an addon to add SOCKS proxy support to your browser. I suggest "FoxyProxy Standard" which is available for both [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/foxyproxy-standard/gcknhkkoolaabfmlnjonogaaifnjlfnp?hl=en) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/).
  Configuring Foxyproxy is simple: go to option page > select the proxy named "Default" (probably with blue icon) > click on "Edit Selection", Then configure it as below:

[image: Configure Foxyproxy standard to use with tor]

And finally, whenever you want, tell your browser to "use proxy Default for all URLs":

[image]

P.S. You can use `Shift+PrtScr` to take screenshot of an "area" rather than all the screen.